# Unable to connect Arduin Uno with inbuilt wifi to internet

Tags: arduino-esp8266

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vx5t.jpg)

This is the board that I'm using Arduino Uno with inbuilt wifi. I'm unable to connect it to my wifi network
I tried doing what is mentioned in the link

https://www.trojanc.co.za/2017/11/05/arduino-uno-wifi-network-setup/

But the webpage won't open
Then I also tried uploading the code mentioned in below link to ESP8266 by pushing on    5th ,6th,and 7th dip switch

https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/readme.html

But it still does not connect to the internet 
On the terminal it shows

```
Hard resetting via rts pin
```

Nothing is visible on serial monitor or arduino IDE
Thanks in advance

Comment: the WiFi is not built in. only on-board. trojanc has Arduino Uno WiFi Developer Edition, you have Robotdyn Uno+WiFi https://robotdyn.com/uno-wifi-r3-atmega328p-esp8266-32mb-flash-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some switch to control connection between USB, Atmega and ESP8266/Wifi
pin 1 and 2 on : Atmega connect to ESP8266 there is not connection to USB/Computer
pin 3 and 4 on : USB/Computer connect to Atmega, so you can upload a skecth
pin 5 and 6 on : USB/Computer connect to ESP8266/Wifi

make sure you have been setup this switch correctly depend on your need.